# Query a Google Spreadsheet (use as an external database

Tags: database, google-docs

I have a small local library and we have entered all our books into a Google Spreadsheet. We would like to allow users to search for a book via a basic SEARCH form on our website, and get results from the spreadsheet. Our simple site hosting does not have MySQL. Is this in any way possible?
Mark

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a simple web app using [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/) attached to the spreadsheet that loaded all of you books into a local array and then filtered them and sent this output back to the user using the HTMLService. You could also look at [the Google Charts Query Language](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage) to do the query, copy in the ES5 filter function or look at the ArrayLib GAS library for the filtering.